# Is Bluetooth communication between Raspberry Pi and iPhone possible?

Tags: ios, raspberry-pi, bluetooth

I can connect to Raspberry Pi with the default Bluetooth settings on my iPhone.

However, I want to send and receive data between Raspberry Pi and iPhone as well as Bluetooth connection.

In the case of Android, they use an app called 'blueterm', but the iPhone App store doesn't have the same app.

I've installed similar apps, but Raspberry Pi doesn't appear on the list.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: You will need something running on the Raspberry Pi to either create a BLE service or connect to one and an app running on the iPhone to do the opposite- connect to a service or advertise one. iPhone's can't connect to a device using "Serial Port Protocol" SPP, which is probably what Blueterm does

Answer (score 4):

In general, it is possible to access an RPi from an iPhone, but this is limited to *Bluetooth LE*. If, on the other hand, you want to use a *Bluetooth Classic* service like the *Serial Port Profile(SPP)*, then this is not possible with an iPhone for you as a private person.

In case you as a company want to develop a product that uses *Bluetooth Classic* and should communicate with Apple devices, you at least have the possibility to do this via Apples [Apple's MFi](https://mfi.apple.com/) licensing programme (Made for iPhone/iPod/iPad). But be warned, this is very complex and expensive.

Answer (score 3):

I guess Raspberry Pi works on BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy),
Try this app to connect your Raspberry Pi with iPhone & discover the services.

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ble-scanner-4-0/id1221763603?platform=iphone

Comment: There's also **nRF Connect for Mobile**.